# Determine the library or libraries used by the /sbin/init and /bin/sh in FreeBSD

Tags: shell, freebsd, init, utilities

How to determine the library or libraries being used by the `/sbin/init` and the `/bin/sh` in FreeBSD? Is it dynamically linked or static?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Using `file` and `ldd`:

```bash
$ file /bin/sh
/bin/sh: ELF 64-bit LSB pie executable, x86-64, version 1 (FreeBSD), dynamically linked, interpreter /libexec/ld-elf.so.1, for FreeBSD 13.1, FreeBSD-style, stripped
$ ldd /bin/sh
/bin/sh:
        libedit.so.8 => /lib/libedit.so.8 (0x80108d000)
        libc.so.7 => /lib/libc.so.7 (0x8010c8000)
        libncursesw.so.9 => /lib/libncursesw.so.9 (0x8014d2000)
```

```bash
$ file /sbin/init
/sbin/init: ELF 64-bit LSB executable, x86-64, version 1 (FreeBSD), statically linked, for FreeBSD 13.1, FreeBSD-style, stripped
$ ldd /sbin/init
ldd: /sbin/init: not a dynamic ELF executable
```

`/bin/sh` is dynamically linked, and `/sbin/init` is (not surprisingly) statically linked.